# Multi delete record

Tags: c#, .net

I have array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds100.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
```

How to delete multi record for each value
using c#, dot.net?

Comment: Tag your questions better (e.g. the language/framework).

Comment: As he says give us `more` informations, more `code` : What do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql 2005 then you can use xml to insert multiple records.

See this example. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/InsertingCollection.aspx

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.